# How to merge elements of dictionary with elements of list of lists of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, merge, zip

I have a dictionary in a list:

```
[{'selectionId': 47999}, {'selectionId': 55190}, {'selectionId': 58805}]
```

and also a list of lists of dictionaries:

```
[[{'price': 2.04, 'size': 45.35}, {'price': 2.02, 'size': 7404.31}, {'price': 2.0, 'size': 15485.06}], [{'price': 4.3, 'size': 2493.19}, {'price': 4.2, 'size': 5627.74}, {'price': 4.1, 'size': 1489.93}], [{'price': 3.5, 'size': 5785.37}, {'price': 3.45, 'size': 4404.69}, {'price': 3.4, 'size': 4917.9}]]
```

I want to 'zip' the elements of the first dictionary with each element in the dictionaries of the list of lists, like the following:

```
[[{'selectionId': 47999, 'price': 2.04, 'size': 45.35}, {'selectionId': 47999, 'price': 2.02, 'size': 7404.31}, {'selectionId': 47999, 'price': 2.0, 'size': 15485.06}]...
```

and so on. How could I do this? I have tried the `{**x, **y}` syntax but doesn't work how I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pprint import pprint

l1 = [{"selectionId": 47999}, {"selectionId": 55190}, {"selectionId": 58805}]
l2 = [
    [
        {"price": 2.04, "size": 45.35},
        {"price": 2.02, "size": 7404.31},
        {"price": 2.0, "size": 15485.06},
    ],
    [
        {"price": 4.3, "size": 2493.19},
        {"price": 4.2, "size": 5627.74},
        {"price": 4.1, "size": 1489.93},
    ],
    [
        {"price": 3.5, "size": 5785.37},
        {"price": 3.45, "size": 4404.69},
        {"price": 3.4, "size": 4917.9},
    ],
]

for a, b in zip(l1, l2):
    for d in b:
        d.update(a)

pprint(l2)
```

Prints:

```py
[[{'price': 2.04, 'selectionId': 47999, 'size': 45.35},
  {'price': 2.02, 'selectionId': 47999, 'size': 7404.31},
  {'price': 2.0, 'selectionId': 47999, 'size': 15485.06}],
 [{'price': 4.3, 'selectionId': 55190, 'size': 2493.19},
  {'price': 4.2, 'selectionId': 55190, 'size': 5627.74},
  {'price': 4.1, 'selectionId': 55190, 'size': 1489.93}],
 [{'price': 3.5, 'selectionId': 58805, 'size': 5785.37},
  {'price': 3.45, 'selectionId': 58805, 'size': 4404.69},
  {'price': 3.4, 'selectionId': 58805, 'size': 4917.9}]]
```